# Codeigniter local to live CssJs//Boostrap error

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I have just recently pushed my CodeIgniter project from local development to live using FTP, I have updated the config and database files also to match the base URL and database details.

immediately after loading can visually see the site but the styling involving the Css/Js/ and Boostrap are not working yet, I linked all using base URL before pushing the project live, I have tried everything but nothing seems to fix the problem, any suggestions?

```
.htacces file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test_abc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(index.php|images|css|fonts|js|robots.txt)
```

Comment: Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). `are not working` is not a helpful problem description. `I have tried everything` also does not tell us anything. Have you done some basic debugging, for example looked at your browser's devtools, or your web server, PHP, and Codeigniter logs? Please edit your question and add details, otherwise it is likely to be closed as lacking details.

Comment: show your .htaccess, please. *are Not working Yet*, what does that mean? can you see the page, but it's not styled? Or can't you see anything? Or do you get an error message? What is your browser's console (F12) saying, any errors?

Comment: @Vickel yes i can see the page but its not styled yet all the style sheets are linked.

Comment: @Makaveli Please attache your browser console errors and also  how you provided link of script and css in your code, also what have you set base url in config file?

Comment: @Makaveli I assume you've hosted to Linux. The casing of your css/jss files(names &paths) in the ```<link>``` and ```<script>``` tags should match.... Linux is CASE-SensiTivE. Try cross-checking...